# Must be authenticated error using Alchemy RPC URL

Tags: foundry, alchemy, sepolia

I am getting this error

```
Error: 
(code: -32000, message: Must be authenticated!, data: None)
```

When running this command

```
forge script script/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol --rpc-url $SEPOLIA_RPC_URL --private-key $PRIVATE_KEY --broadcast
```

I have verified the RPC URL is correct

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

Hi found a solution hope this helps anyone

```js
{.env file}
PRIVATE_KEY=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
RPC_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8545
Sepolia_RPC_URL=https://eth-sepolia.g.alchemy.com/v2/xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
```

```
source .env

forge script script/DeploySimpleStorage.s.sol --rpc-url $Sepolia_RPC_URL --private-key $PRIVATE_KEY --broadcast
```